# How to make a selectbox required using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having this in mind

```
$("div input[id = 'weight']").attr('required','required');
```

how can I use it for a select box #cargo to make it required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add the `required` attribute to a select element, as long as the first `option` has a value of `""`, an empty string.

*NOTE:*  `required` *is not supported < IE9*

### example:

```js
$('select#required').attr('required',1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

  <select id="required">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

### documentation: (bold text is important but not in the doc)

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element

> The required attribute is a boolean
>   attribute.
>   When specified, the user
>   will be required to select a value
>   before submitting the form.
>
> If a select element
>
> - has a required attribute specified,
> - does not have a multiple attribute specified,
> - and has  a display size of 1;
> - **and if the value 
>     of the first option element in the
>     select element's list of options (if
>     any) is the empty string**,
> - and that
>     option element's parent node is the
>     select element (and not an optgroup
>     element),
>
> then that option is the
>   select element's placeholder label
>   option.

Comment: Thank you, please tell me, how to remove the required attribute with the same method?

Comment: The `required` attribute is boolean, so any string (except for empty) will set it, the number 1 will set it, and `true` will set it.  To remove, you can use the number 0, or an empty string or `false`.  So use either `attr('required',0);`, `attr('required',false);`, or `attr('required','');` to remove the attribute.